# Creating an Array of objects from the Facebook SDK in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

Im new to Swift and IOS programming in general so maybe im just google ing the wrong things

I have the Facebook SDK working and returning the albums. Now i want the data in objects named Album. These Album objects will be the datasource of my collection view cells

When trying to do this i run into the following problem:

i can't get my objects into my object array! here is the code i have so far:

```
  var i = 0
    var list: [String] = []
    for rawFeed : AnyObject in data {
        if rawFeed is FBGraphObject {
            if var jsonFeed = rawFeed as? FBGraphObject {
                var app = jsonFeed["name"] as String
                list.append(app)

                 var i = Album(albumName: jsonFeed["name"] as String , albumId:jsonFeed["id"] as Int,count: jsonFeed["count"] as Int)
                arrayOfAlbums.append(test)
                i++
            }
        }
```

I thought i would use the value of `i` as object name.

like this:

```
arrayOfAlbums = {
[0] => AlbumObject0,
[1] => albumobject1
}
```

when trying to do this i get the following error on the `i++` rule:
'Album' is not identical to 'CGFloat'

what am i doing wrong and where can i improve my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redefining the `i` variable - I think you probably wanted to name it `test`.

Note that you can simplify your code here:

```
if rawFeed is FBGraphObject {
    if var jsonFeed = rawFeed as? FBGraphObject {
```

as:

```
if let jsonFeed = rawFeed as? FBGraphObject {
```

Comment: i wanted to name the object album the value of i: like this|
i=0|
var i.value = album|

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. `i` is already defined as an `Int` variable, and you're using it to count the number of objects that are added to the `arrayOfAlbums` array. Why do you want to reuse the same variable name for a different purpose?

Comment: I want to use the value of i as an unique name for my object

Comment: `i` is defined as integer, then you redefine it locally as `Album`, so how would it be a name? However, ok if you want that to be called `i`, then rename the outer integer variable to something else, like `var counter = 0`, and update the increment line to `counter++`.

Comment: well i thought as newbie to Swift i could make an object album with the value of i and append that to my arrayOfAlbums to create an unique name for my object. But thats not possible (i think i can make that up from you answer) shall edit the question