# Get array of facebook albums in swift using Facebook SDK 4.1

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm attempting to fetch an array of a users facebook albums via the new Facebook SDK 4.1 using the following Swift code:

```
func getAlbumList()
{
    var FBAlbums = [String]()
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me?fields=albums", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            println("fetched data: \(result)")

            let graphData = result.valueForKey("data") as Array;

            for obj:FBGraphObject in graphData{
                let desc = obj.description;
                println(desc);
                let name = obj.valueForKey("name") as String;
                println(name);
            }

        }
    })
}
```

The FB SDK query is working ok as the result value contains all the data from facebook (it prints fine), however any attempt to actually turn this into an array is failling.

Using XCode 6.3 this gives the following errors:

`let graphData = result.valueForKey("data") as Array;` = `'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'Array<T>'`

`for obj:FBGraphObject in graphData{` = `Use of undeclared type 'FBGraphObject'`

I can't seem to find any information about what has replaced FBGraphObject, or why I can't convert the result to an array.

Articles used as background (but out of date it seems):

[Creating an Array of objects from the Facebook SDK in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906856/creating-an-array-of-objects-from-the-facbook-sdk-in-swift)

http://selise.ch/build-a-facebook-album-browser-using-swift/

Comment: You can't just cast as "Array", you have to give the type of the array, even if it's just `[AnyObject]`. In your case, try `let graphData = result.valueForKey("data") as [FBGraphObject]`. (Just a guess from your code, I'm not a Facebook SDK user)

Answer (score 3):

Just change this line of your code:

```
let graphData = result.valueForKey("data") as Array;
```

To:

```
self.dict = result["data"] as! NSArray
```

This works for me retrieving user photos from facebook:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/photos", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, source"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    if (error == nil){
        self.dict = result["data"] as! NSArray

        for item in self.dict { // loop through data items

            if let urlString = item["source"]! {
                let url = NSURL(string: urlString as! String)
                let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                self.socialPhotoCollection.append(image!)

            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for getting all albums in a different way

**Swift 3x:**

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/albums", parameters: ["fields":"id,name,user_photos"], httpMethod: "GET").start(completionHandler: {  (connection, result, error) in


        print(result!)
})
```